# Azure function v2 ServiceBusTrigger control retry count

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

By default when a processing a message in an Azure Function v2, the function will be retried 10 times on error.

I actually want to reduce this but I can't find how to do it?

```
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%EventsTopicName%", "%EventsSubscriptionName%", Connection = "GetEventsConnectionString")]Message mySbMsg, ILogger log)
{
    // Code to process a message
}
```

Comment: It seems to be controlled by the [QueueDescription.MaxDeliveryCount property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.maxdeliverycount?view=azure-dotnet) and has a default value of 10, you could set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was this, the ServiceBus is created using Azure ARM templates.

In order to reduce the number of retries, I was looking to do it in the code which was wrong. This is controlled in the ARM templates with the following property in the Topics config:

```
"maxDeliveryCount ": 2
```

When maxDeliveryCount is not set, by default the value is 10.